# return unique max when using aggregate (R)

Tags: r

How can I get R to deal with tie-breakers when using `aggregate( ..., FUN=max)` and only return a UNIQUE maximum. OK to pick arbitrarily.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you share an example? I'm not sure I understand, because if the max is duplicated, `max` still only returns one value (which seems to fall in line with your "OK to pick arbitrarily")... Maybe you could demo on the built-in `mtcars` data?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you only want a result when a "winner" was declared? You could write your own function, and call that in `aggregate`. Something like this should work (not tested, feel free to post a minimum reproducible example, and I'll test it):

```
winner <- function( x ) {
    if( max( x ) > min( x ) ) {
        return( max( x ) )
    } else {
        return( NA )
    }
}

aggregate( ..., FUN = winner )
```